# TypeError: Object #<Promise> has no method 'forEach' mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, foreach, mongoose

I am trying to copy a document from one collection to another using MongoDB and nodejs in visual studio. Here's what I am trying to do:

```
var newcollection = db.get('mynewdata');
var oldcollection = db.get('myusercollection');
var userName = req.body.username;

oldcollection.find({ "username" : userName }).forEach(function (docs) {
     newcollection.insert(docs);
});
```

On the Mongo website it says that collection.find() should return a cursor which should be able to use the forEach() method.  However, it's not returning a cursor object and forEach doesn't seem to be defined for whatever its returning.

I get the error from the subject line that says: `TypeError: Object #<Promise> has no method 'forEach'`

Any ideas as to why it is giving me this error?

Comment: Are you using https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongodb ?

Comment: Are you using Mongoose?

Comment: yes I am using mongoose

Comment: Then you need to use the Mongoose API definitions and not the native API for things like [`find`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On the Mongo website

That may be the case with the core mongo API, but not the Node.js module.

But also, make sure you're using the right version of the Node library (and the official one too).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
oldcollection.find({ "username" : userName }).exec(function(err, results){
    if(err){
        throw err
    } else {
        results.forEach(function(docs){
            newcollection.insert(docs)
        })
    }
});
```

I think your problem is the response from the query is an object. This method works for me.